# DataContext class not found in XAML Designer (while everything looks fine)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, datacontext

I am trying to set my datacontext in the XAML file via

```
<Window x:Class="LocationScout.SettingsDeleteWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:LocationScout.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Delete" Height="315" Width="350" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:SettingsDeleteDisplayItem/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The XAML editor, however, shows the error "The name "SettingsDeleteDisplayItem" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:LocationScout.ViewModel".

The view model class looks fine for me:

```
namespace LocationScout.ViewModel
{
    public class SettingsDeleteDisplayItem : BaseObservableObject
    {
         private long _countryAreaCountToDelete;

         public long CountryAreaCountToDelete
         {
            get => _countryAreaCountToDelete;
            set
            {
                _countryAreaCountToDelete = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Building the solution works fine without error. Any idea? Many thanks.

Comment: The designer has a (deserved) terrible reputation for false positives on errors. If your program runs, you just have to ignore it.

Comment: Oh.  This is in the designer?  Rebuild your project.  If that doesn't work, restart Visual Studio and rebuild your project.  Failing that, try changing ViewModel to lower case, as in `xmlns:viewModel`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Rebuilding did not help, but I changed to lower case and restarted Visual Studio - now it works. Many thanks. Really a but in the designer...

Comment: The reason this might have been an issue is because `ViewModel` (in upper case) appears in your namespace declarations.

Comment: I see that sounds reasonable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As advised by @RobertHarvey in a comment, I changed to lowercase and restarted Visual Studio:

> try changing `ViewModel` to lower case, as in `xmlns:viewModel`.
>
> The reason this might have been an issue is because `ViewModel` (in
> upper case) appears in your namespace declarations.

Now it works.

Just rebuilding the solution did not help (I tried that earlier).